# Select all options in HTML using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

So I am trying to select all the options on a website using VBA.
the options sometimes changes but i want to select all of them.

the below is the html code for the selection menu.

```
<select class="locationSelect" id="ReceiptLocations" multiple="multiple" name="ReceiptLocations" size="10"><option value="7">Bayhurst 1</option>
<option value="157">Union Parkway Belt</option>
<option value="260">Union SSMDA</option>
<option value="261">Union WDA</option>
<option value="244">Welwyn</option>
<option value="83343">Whitewood Receipt</option>
</select>
```

My current code in excel is as follow:

```
Sub extract()
    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim ohtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim objOption As Object

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate ("http://itbidfloors.transcanada.com/")
oIE.Visible = True


' Wait while IE loading
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until oIE.ReadyState = 4


For Each objOption In oIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("locationSelect").getElementsByID("ReceiptLocations").Options
        objOption.Selected = True
Next

End Sub
```

The error i run into is the object doesnt support this property or method.
i am using a for loop in this case because i want to select all the options that are available.

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `For Each objOption In oIE.Document.getElementByID("ReceiptLocations").Options`  The `id`attribute should be unique per document, so you don't need to first filter by class, and you have an extra `s` in your method name.

Comment: Thanks Tim! worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub extract()
    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim ohtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim objOption As Object

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate ("http://itbidfloors.transcanada.com/")
oIE.Visible = True


' Wait while IE loading
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until oIE.ReadyState = 4


For Each objOption In oIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("locationSelect").getElementsByID("ReceiptLocations").Options
        objOption.Selected = True
Next

End Sub
```